# Bit local repo: Remove a file from a old commit

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

Git beginner here...

I use it with Visual Studio exclusively. I've made 18 commits since the last push to the remote server and commit number 5 has a large file in it that I did not intent to be in there. Because it is over 100MB, I cannot push to the remote server.

How do I edit that old commit and remove that file?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the command-line git tool, it's easy. Assuming your remote tracking branch is `origin/master`:

`git rebase -i origin/master`

This will bring up an editor containing a list of your unpushed commits. Find the commit you want to edit, change the word `pick` to `edit`, save and exit.

You should see a message stating that you're now editing the commit in question. Now just:

```
git rm big_bad_file
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can delete commit number 5 from commit history.
`git log` -to see the various commit, with their hash values

and use `git reset hash value`- to uncommit that from history and also remove form staging area and then you can delete that file and commit again